# convLSTM2d w/ functional API

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have an autoencoder for image compression, where the encoded tensor has the shape: (batch_size, 12, 64, 48).

batch_size is the number of images being fed in a batch,
12 is the number of channels of this last encoder layer, which has a 
64x48 width/height.

I want to input this to a ConvLSTM2D layer, and i would like the output of the ConvLSTM2D to have the same dimension as the input of the ConvLSTM2D.

The intention is to see image reconstruction on a video sequence, rather than unordered images from a dataset.

Placing a ConvLSTM2d between an encoder/decoder in a autoencoder architecture has been difficult, especially because most examples use the Sequential API, and i want to use the functional API in Keras.

I tried reshaping the input but the error persists

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K


def LSTM_layer(input):

    input = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(input, axis=-1)
    lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=12, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), data_format="channels_first",
                                        input_shape=(None, 12, 64, 48), 
                                        padding='same', return_sequences=True)(input)

    return lstm1

def build_model(input_shape):

    #create an input with input_shape as the size
    input_ = tf.keras.Input(shape=input_shape, name="input_node")
    lstm_features = LSTM_layer(input_)

    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_, outputs=[lstm_features])
    return model

def main():

    input_shape = (12, 64, 48) #this is the size of the tensor which is outputted by my encoder, with channels_first assumed
    model = build_model(input_shape)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Unfortunately, this is throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lstm.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "lstm.py", line 26, in main
    model = build_model(input_shape)
  File "lstm.py", line 20, in build_model
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_, outputs=[lstm_features])
  File "/home/hallab/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 121, in __init__
    super(Model, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hallab/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 80, in __init__
    self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hallab/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/checkpointable/base.py", line 474, in _method_wrapper
    method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hallab/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/network.py", line 224, in _init_graph_network
    '(thus holding past layer metadata). Found: ' + str(x))
ValueError: Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer` (thus holding past layer metadata). Found: Tensor("conv_lst_m2d/transpose_1:0", shape=(?, 12, 12, 48, 1), dtype=float32)
```

Most posts about this error instruct to wrap the operation in a lambda.. but i am not implementing a custom operation here, this should be a keras tf layer... right?

Also, in my implementation, i want the output tensor from the LSTM unit to be the same as the input, can i get some feedback about that as well?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Lambda to wrap the output form K.expand_dims before input it to next layer like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda

def expand_dims(x):
    return K.expand_dims(x, 1)

def expand_dims_output_shape(input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], 1, input_shape[1])

def LSTM_layer(input_):
    lstm1 = Lambda(expand_dims, expand_dims_output_shape)(input_)
    lstm1 = tf.keras.layers.ConvLSTM2D(filters=12, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), data_format="channels_first",                             padding='same', return_sequences=False)(lstm1)
    return lstm1
```

Comment: would you like a job?